# Self-help questions

Tags: discussion, support, suggestions

I am most active at Biology and Cognitive Sciences.SE. Both sites quite aggressively close every question on self-help, and I am one of those aggressive close voters, because I support the thought that anonymous folks shouldn't pretend to be able to diagnose a problem through a computer screen without having even seen the person.

However, looking at the questions here at Health.SE I think self-help questions are allowed. Should 'we' at Biology and Cognitive Sciences not close-vote self-helps, but instead vote for migration to Health.SE?

Comment: Yes. I was on Biology a couple of days ago and wondered why mods weren't sending some of these questions our way. We can edit borderline questions to fit here. If they are a poor fit, well, at least someone tried!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. Some of the self help questions would not fit here either, as they would be applicable to only that person, or would require a level of diagnosis that doesn't really fit on the site.

If, however, the question would offer value to a broader audience it may fit here. I would suggest reading [this meta question](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here) and answers along with the links therein, and if you think a question would fit here, go ahead and flag it for your moderators. We have certainly flagged some from here for both Cog and Biology SE sites.