# The scope for questions listed on the tour page is weirdly narrow

Tags: discussion, support

The scope for questions is currently:

> - Environmental or nutritional factors that affect health
> - The ways that diseases and injuries affect people
> - The health effects of processes such as pregnancy and aging
> - Medications and other interventions that are used to treat diseases

This seems overly limited. I would expect to be able to ask questions such as:

- "If one or more of a person's blood test results is outside of the normal range, does that necessarily mean that he/she is sick/unwell?"
- "Why are depression and anxiety sometime used interchangeably or together to describe the same condition?"
- "What do you do when two doctors give conflicting diagnoses?"

and so on. All of these are currently out-of-scope, it seems. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is asking for personal medical advice. Answering personal medical questions can lead to misdiagnosis or wrong therapy and can harm the OP or other users, which is one of the most important reasons these are off-topic. Other reasons are discussed [here](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here).

Whole books have been written as the answer to your second question (disregarding that the claim in it is imprecise and partly inaccurate). Hence, it is too broad.

In a general case, the response to your third question is: ask a third doctor. (And a fourth and a fifth one if need be). If you ask about a specific situation - it would be a personal medical advice question, so same as 1.

All in all, the site is in beta and topics listed in the help centre or on the tour page are more guidelines than rules set in stone. For instance, questions on medical terminology or the type of doctor you might see for a specific problem are on topic, although they don't easily fit in one of the listed four. On the other hand, the questions on the subjects that are listed as off topic are strictly treated as such. This applies all across SE.

You know of an area that isn't off-topic, but isn't covered by the on-topic guidelines? Write about it on meta for the community to discuss. But specific example questions aren't of much help, especially if they are of the type that would promptly be closed.

Comment: No, the question does not ask for advice, it asks for what blood test results mean, generally; it doesn't refer to any specific test or any specific result, nor to the medical condition of a specific person. As for the rest of your answer - it's circular logic. I know these issues are off-topic, I'm writing on meta to suggest that they shouldn't be and that many people would expect them to be on-topic on a site named "health".

Comment: And perhaps I should mention that I _don't_ need a response to these questions, I gave them as an example.

Comment: @einpoklum Well, in the case of a general question of blood tests, that is way too broad. Tons ob books in medicinal biochemistry are dedicated to that. In addition, one of the ways diseases affect people is by affecting the concentrations of various substances in their blood. As I said, determining what is on-topic example by example is not very efficient. It's better to define an area which would cover it. Ranting "this site does not meet my expectations" won't help anyone. If you don't like it - don't use it. Oh, wait, you aren't using health SE anyway...

Comment: @einpoklum: **Only a professional doctor** can give you a sound diagnosis *after they examined you*. I'd really like to see how Tele-examining via the internet works!

Comment: @Narusan: Who said anything about diagnoses? Somehow people refuse to understand what I asked. ... you know what? Maybe it's the use of the first person that's misleading. Let me edit that away.

Comment: *"If one or more of a person's blood test results is outside of the normal range, does that necessarily mean that he/she is sick/unwell?"* is obviously asking for medical recommendation. This is off-topic. *"What do blood test results indicate?"* would not be considered off-topic

Comment: @einpoklum The problem is that no one can answer this question profoundly. Necessary? No. But very high probable. How's that going to help anyone. That is why these questions are ruled out. They can only be misleading because people with **clear** blood test results might get a wrong impression of their tests. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @Narusan: Your insistence that these kinds of questions are personal medical advice are what, I suspect, would make your site baffling to users and makes the scope so limited as to stunt your potential for popularity. But - knock yourselves out.

Comment: @einpoklum We shall knock ourselves out then. We are not going for popularity. Instead, we know that we will never be able to replace any professional doctor. Misjudgements by us could lead to severe complications. We don't want to be popular, we want to help the people that ask the most. There is no need for you to accept this, feel free to ask for another stackexchange site for this purpose. Thank you very much for your understanding.