# Off Topic? Tools/Tutorials/Off-Site Resource

Tags: discussion

4. Questions asking us to recommend or **find a tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Does that carry over for this? [Heart Attack Risk Score calculation](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/heart-attack-risk-score-calculation)

The Help for HealthSE doesn't have those rules listed from SO.

Here is a MetaSE post that is related: [Are questions of the type "What *product* is this?" allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249917/are-questions-of-the-type-what-product-is-this-allowed)